# NLog's ConditionalDebug in Common.Logging?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog, common.logging

NLog has two different types of "log a debug message" calls: Debug() and ConditionalDebug() (and similarly Trace() and ConditionalTrace()).  The difference is that for a Release build, the "Conditional" calls don't even get emitted into the compiled exe/dll/whatever.

I don't see support for this feature in Common.Logging.  Am I missing it, or is it not supported? If it's not supported, is there any other good logging abstraction layer that does support it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported in Common.Logging, but I'm pretty sure you can add it with a Pull Request.